# How to send url parameter from one request to another dynamically in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am sending an Http request with some parameters say username and contact_number out of which username is generated dynamically. here i want to use the same username to send in different request which is supposed to be sent after completion of 1st one.

How can we do that with jmeter. please help me. thanks.

Comment: How do you generate this `username` parameter?

Comment: i am generating the username parameter as  sam_1 , sam_2, for which i am using random function of jmeter(function helper dialog). now i want to use same username for different request which should be sent after completion of 1st

Answer (score 1):

Given you use [__Random() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) to generate a number like:

```
sam_${__Random(1,100)}
```

You can add a 3rd parameter to the __Random() function which will store generateed value into a JMeter Variable, like:

```
sam_${__Random(1,100,postfix)}
```

So you will be able to access the generated username later on as simple as:

```
sam_${postfix}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more information on using functions in JMeter tests

Comment: that's fine . but how to make sure that the second request is sent after completion of first request , that means after getting response code as "200 : OK" from the first request.

Comment: Each JMeter thread executes requests sequentially. If you need to execute 2nd request only if first request is successful you can put it under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) and use `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` as the condition